# In which location install npm and npm module in existing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, npm

I have already a CodeIgniter application using RestClient and mysql.Chat is running well via Push Notification.
Now Need to integrate real time chat with node js and socket.io. I am new for node js.
Please suggest where I install npm or include the npm module.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The node modules can be installed globally or locally. Usually it goes into root of the project.

Put your project dependencies into `package.json` file and then execute `npm install` command.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Thanks. Then what is path of the server.js in which I can import module i.e. express,mysql etc.

Comment: The best solution would be to separate CodeIgniter and Node.js projects, because it is a two projects (they just working with each another). The folder structure of the Node.js project depends on the details of your project, but for inspiration you can take a look into https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html